# SqlCeCommand nullable values

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

My code:

```
SqlCeConnection sql = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\DB.sdf");
sql.Open();
cmd = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO xxx(aaa) VALUES(@aaa)", sql);
String param = null;  //doesn't work
//String param = "blah" //works
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aaa", param);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //(1)
sql.Close();
```

(1) throws an exception when `param` is null. Database allows value in collumn `aaa` to be null. How can I insert null into table xxx ?

Exception:
`Parameterized query 'INSERT INTO xxx(aaa) VALUES(@aaa)' expects a parameter value which was not supplied.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `DBNull.Value` instead:

```
var param = DBNull.Value;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
var param = DBNull.Value;
```

null isn't the same thing as DBNull

Comment: Can DBNull.Value be cast to String?